# Moving on forward after knowing the fundamentals of the c#

Tags: c#

I'm beginner c# programmer.

So far I have learned stuff like:

- If Statements
- For and While loops
- Classes
- Arrays
- Functions
- And other basic stuff.

I'm able to create most of the basic applications.

My question would be:

Where to move after this? Where to learn more?

Should I look for source codes of applications and read them, or perhaps try something else?

Regards,

-Loganl33t

Comment: Try to answer other's question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

The way I taught myself and I think it helped more than anything was to constantly come up with new programs to create that solved some sort of problem or helped make some process easier. It can be hard to come up with stuff but I would look for opportunities at work or home. One of the most useful things I made was very early on. It was a little utility app that would basically copy, paste and rename a file to input weekly sales data for my dads business. In the past I had to do it manually for him so it was a good learning opportunity for me that also produced something very useful.

The natural progression that occurred was such that each application I made was more complex then the one prior to it. Over the course of 2 years I probably created 10 applications with the last one finally landing me a job as a software dev. I probably created 20+ that never went anywhere but you learn the most from your failures.

I started off by making small utilities that were useful to me at my job when I started coding as well as things that would help my parents at their businesses. It's hard to come up with ideas but I think that's the key. Always have something in the works and always be working on something. It's the best way to learn what you don't know and it forces you to figure out the solution.

It's hard to give a direct answer to your question because there is no correct set path that can be applied to everyone. If you want some structure, read some more books and do all the coding exercises in those until you are comfortable enough to try stuff on your own.

Most importantly though, just keep going and one day it will click.

**One other thing**

Learn about design patterns early on and try to apply them to everything you do. It's hard and it sucks at first, but it pays huge dividends in the long term.

Comment: Agree. Practice is the best thing you can do to learn stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It's great that you are learning C#. Your biggest friend will be the courses that are out there.  I would look at PluralSight. Anything you want to learn is there.